# How to store a markdown editor content as html tags in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to store the markdown editor content as html format in flutter. I am using flutter_markdown but I am not able to do. My code is given below, In this need to add convert the markdown editor content to html format.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:markdown_editor_plus/markdown_editor_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: const [
          MarkdownAutoPreview(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Markdown Auto Preview',
            ),
            emojiConvert: true,
            // maxLines: 10,
            // minLines: 1,
            // expands: true,
          ),
          SplittedMarkdownFormField(
            markdownSyntax: '## Headline',
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Splitted Markdown FormField',
            ),
            emojiConvert: true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please verify the code and give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter_markdown` is the package that provides *flutter widgets* to display markdown.

If you want the HTML, just use the plain `markdown` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/markdown), it should be easy:

Their example is:

```
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart';

void main() {
  print(markdownToHtml('Hello *Markdown*'));
  //=> <p>Hello <em>Markdown</em></p>
}
```

I doubt converting markdown to HTML gets any easier.

---

You can *get* the markdown by passing a [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html):

In your state class:

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

and then in your build method:

```
MarkdownFormField(
    controller: _controller,
```

Then, you can do everything you want, that you otherwise do with a controller. Including accessing the `.text` property to get your text.

Comment: I need to add a markdown editor and take the data from the editor and store data as in html format.

Comment: Okay... so what exactly are you having problems with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I generated a markdown editor using markdown_editor_plus but I want the save the content in HTML format for future use.

Comment: Is it possible to make a markdown editor using flutter_markdown?

Comment: I thought you had an editor with `markdown_editor_plus`, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I need one markdown editor and store the input as html format..

Comment: I know... you told us that 2 days ago. You still have *not* told us, is what exactly your problem is. Where are you stuck? What *doesn't* work in your program? We are not a service to code your application, we help with *problems* you may encounter. So... what is your *problem*? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be helpful in getting to a question people here can answer.

Comment: using the markdown_editor_plus created I editor. But I am not able to export the data to html format from the editor.

Comment: So, can you show us what you *have*? I cannot possible tell you what you do wrong, if you don't show us what you *do*.

Comment: I updated my code base can you please check.

Comment: This text how i will convert as html tags.

Comment: @Krishnaprasad It's right there in my answer, the first code block.

Comment: If I am using import package:markdown_editor_plus/markdown_editor_plus.dart'; and import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart'; in a single file I am getting so error like, The name 'Text' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' and 'package:markdown/src/ast.dart'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

Comment: Okay. Did you google that? Did you try to fix it? What happened when you did?